# how to perform a for loop inside map

Tags: reactjs

I am looping over records and inside there I have a star rating. If the star rating is 4, then I need a for loop to output 4 span tags. In php I had a foreach loop and inside that a for loop, but I am trying to convert it to React now.

```
  <?php foreach ( $foo as $bar ): ?>
           <?php for ( $x = 1; $x <= $stars; $x++ ): ?>
               <span>&#9733;</span>
           <?php endfor;?>
           <?php for ( $x = 1; $x <= 5 - $stars; $x++ ): ?>
               <span class="greyed">&#9733;</span>
           <?php endfor; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

React:

```
    {reviews.map((r) => (
      <>
        <div className="stars">
          {for loop would go here
           <span>&#9733;</span>
          }
        </div>
      </>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array full of dummy values and use `map` again:

```
    {reviews.map((r) => (
      <>
        <div className="stars">
          {Array(stars).fill().map(() => <span>&#9733;</span>)}
        </div>
      </>
    ))}
```

Comment: That is superb, thanks. Just realised that I forgot the bit to show greyed out stars if not 5 stars. (added to original question)

Comment: @user8463989 Use the same method and create an array again? This time it's `Array(5 - stars)`.

Comment: Oh right, simple as that then. Thanks!!